# Android build number

Tags: android, gradle

I need your help. I wish to add the build name of my app to the gradle file. The thing is I do NOT want it to be visible to user on the market, so this:

`versionName "3.1.0.5486"`

does not suits me. But I need it in a way so I can read it via code (In the about screen for example) and increment it each build. How can you advise me?

Comment: you wanted to version name programmaticaly

Comment: Step #1: Come up with your preferred solution for knowing the build number and incrementing it. For example, you could use a private `.properties` file. Step #2: Use that value to rename the APK file. Step #3: Use that same value in `buildConfigField` to add a field to the `BuildConfig` class that you can read in Java, or use that same value in `resValue` to add a new resource (e.g., string resource) that you can use in a layout resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use standard versionCode parameter. You can read it from code using

> BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE.

You can set the version code and name inside the defaultConfig element in the build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

And use it as is:

```
String.format(getString(R.string.some_text_with_int_placeholder), BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE);
```

If you want create your own variable just use `buildConfigField`, something like:

```
 buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "int", "FOO", "42"
            buildConfigField "String", "FOO_STRING", "\"foo\""
            buildConfigField "boolean", "LOG", "true"
        }
}
```

And access it via `BuildConfig.FOO`

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Check this doc https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html for more information. In a few words versionCode is the same with versionName but supposed to be used as internal app version which isn't showing to users.

Comment: I've added additional example for gradle build script in the answer

Comment: Hi, Thanks... but this is not what I meant. GooglePlay uses version code for storing apk and manage version. I wish it to be something independent.

Comment: Aha. In this case just create new variable in Gradle script via buildConfigField as mentioned CommonsWare in his comment above

Comment: Check up additional example with `buildConfigField` in the answer